# Spring и HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring

Используется Spring 4.3.4.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

    <form:form>
    </form:form>
```

Токен подставляется.
При отправке запросов методом POST получаю соответствующий ответ: "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported"

Если использовать версию Spring 4.2.4 тогда такой проблемы не возникает.
Есть ли решение ?

Comment: Что? Какой запрос? Маппер на пост запрос пробоошен?

Comment: методом POST, проброшено все.  Повторю: 4.2.4 отрабатывает все корректно, а 4.3.4 при тех же условиях нет.

Comment: @xrk используй тогда 4.2.4

Comment: Код контроллера покажите.

Comment: надо добавить `type="POST"`  в форму